# How to loop through several files using gdal and cmd?

Tags: gdal

I have several files which have the tif format.I would like to translate them to ENVI format.
I succeeded for one file but I want to do for the rest of files in the directory.

```
   the first file in the directory is:Ser_W55_20100101_A.tif.
   the second file in the directory is:Ser_W55_20100102_A.tif    and so on .....
```

I am working on windows so I just launch cmd and then wrote the command:

```
 C:\Users>gdal_translate -of "ENVI" D:\Ser_W55_20100101_A.tif D:\Ser_W55_20100101_A.img
```

this worked perfectly. Any ideas please on how to do this for all files and return the same names(with changing from (tif) to ENVI)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a batch file for this, do something like:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET mypath=D:\test\

FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR /B %mypath%*.tif') DO (

    SET infile=%%i
    SET outfile=!infile:.tif=.img!

    gdal_translate -of "ENVI" %mypath%!infile! %mypath%!outfile!

)
```

This only runs in de current directory, if you want to include subfolders, add the `/S` flag to the dir statement. I might be good to check whats happening at first, to do so you can add a `ECHO` in front of the gdal cmd, so `ECHO gdal_translate...`, and add a `PAUSE` at the end. That way it will only print the commands to the console instead of actually running them.

Comment: No `DIR` is a command which lists the contents of a folder, to execute it in a folder other than the current working directory use: `FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR /B D:\Ser\*.tif') DO (`

Comment: Thats because the `DIR /B` command only returns the filename (without folder). You can either add the `/S` flag in the `DIR` statement, which will make it include all subfolders as well. Or also add your path to the gdal cmd. See my update answer, i hope that clarifies it for you.

Comment: No, the `%mypath%` is a variable containing the path, its set on the third line. If you want to change it, do it there.